# java: interleaving string arrays?

Tags: java

So I'm pretty lost. Here's what im tasked to do. I have to Write a Java method named that accepts two Strings (called you and
me) as arguments. The method will return a String consisting of the first character of you, then the
first character of me, then the next character of you, then the next character of me, and so on. For example: interleave("abcdefg", "1234" ) returns a1b2c3d4efg

Comment: Whenever asking question, providing your code snippet is highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String combine(String you, String me) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < me.length(); i++) {
            if (i < you.length()) {
                builder.append(you.charAt(i));
                builder.append(me.charAt(i));
            } else {
                builder.append(me.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

We iterate over the second parameter (must be the longer one for this to work properly), then append each character to the string. It does this long as as we haven't hit the end of the first argument(the smaller one). After that it simply appends the rest of the longer string.
So if we do  `System.out.println(combine("123456789", "abcdefghi");`
 the result will be  `1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void modify(String a1, String b1){

    int index = 0;

    int len1 = a1.length() > b1.length()? a1.length():b1.length();
    int len2 = a1.length() > b1.length()? b1.length():a1.length();

    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++){

        if(len2>0){
            System.out.print(""+a1.charAt(index)+b1.charAt(index));
            index++;
            len2--;
        }
        else{

            if(i<a1.length())
            {
                System.out.print(""+a1.charAt(index));
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(""+b1.charAt(index));
                index++;
            }                       

        }           
    }
```

This modify() takes two strings and whichever string is larger, gets stored in len1 and smaller one gets stored in len2.

'index' is used to extract particular index of the string.

'for' loop iterates over larger string and prints both the strings alternatively.
Then whichever string is larger, rest of its contents are appended.

For example: modify("abcdefg", "1234" ) prints a1b2c3d4efg.